# Core Plot's CPTPlotSpaceDelegate: Correct implementation of zooming and panning

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have implemented the delegates `CPTPlotDataSource` and `CPTPlotSpaceDelegate` in my view controller. I also have set `plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES` and  `self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES`.

However, the methods

`-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint`,

`-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point`,

`-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector` and

`-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate` are not called even though the plot is zoomable.

What did I miss in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did forget to set my delegate: `plotSpace.delegate = self;`